# "Statistically speaking ... "

Tags: grammar, vocabulary

I am looking for a way to express the equivalent of "statistically speaking, ..." (followed by a quote from a paper, or something like that), or pretty much any other grammatical construction that works well for the subject of quoting statistics or papers.

I know the word 統計, but that always results in very cumbersome (and probably wrong) sentences, such as:

> 統計の論文を読んだ、
>   統計の見方から、

I am sure Japanese people will understand what I try to express, but it's hardly correct.

While I honestly care about the answer and do not know it, I have also made this question for meta-discussion: [Who is our target audience?](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9/who-is-our-target-audience/275#275)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try 統計的に言えば....

asked google translate and it makes sense + shorter than what you used and seems more grammatically correct.

Comment: That is incredibly literal. Can someone with experience confirm?

Comment: I'm pretty low-level, but that sounds really human to me!

Comment: This sounds perfectly okay to me. 「統計的に言うと」would suffice as well. 「的」is often used like this. 「文法的には正しい」＝＝ "Grammatically, it's correct." 「文法的に言うと...」== "Grammatically speaking..."

Comment: There are lots of ways. For example 統計的な観点で言うと (live example here: http://a.know-how.fc2.com/ja/1557/) Remember, Google is your friend when determining how widely use a written phrase is.

Comment: I find the "言えば" a little bit too much in casual conversation. In a similar fashion, you can also say "確率的に" without fear.

Answer (score 6):

Some more variations:

> 統計的には...
>
> Statistically, ...

Shorter version of 統計的に言えば.

~的 is quite versatile and, technically, it can be tacked on to almost any noun. ex. お金的には (moneywise), 春的な (spring-like). But excessive or uncommon usage will be frowned upon as slang.

> 統計的見地から言えば...
>
> From the standpoint of statistics, ...

Using 見地 adds objectivity and formality to your statement.

> 統計上は...
>
> According to statistics, ...

Depending on the context, this can sometimes imply that the speaker thinks the truth doesn't lie in the numbers.

Answer (score 5):

> Statistically speaking　統計的に言えば

http://www.raku-eigo.com/index.php?e=21
- Since this is an NHK course (for English), I'd say the Japanese part is pretty safe...